# Transform an indexed Attribute-Value array into Associative array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, entity-attribute-value

I have a big array that contains rows as following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [attribute] => gender
            [value] => male
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [attribute] => first_name
            [value] => test
        )

)
```

I want to convert it into an associative array:

```
Array
(
    [gender] => male
    [first_name] => test
)
```

Is here a built-in PHP function that can do it or should I do it using a Foreach loop?

Comment: How did you end up with the first array? seems weird to have the titles and values like that.

Comment: It's the Entity-Attribute-Value model - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: Does the model define the structure when returned from the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a native function call to convert two columns of data into a flat associiative array.

Call `array_column()` and offer the "values" column as the second parameter and the "keys" parameter as the third parameter.

Bear in mind, if there are duplicate values (or otherwise values that will result in key collisions because of how PHP modifies certain data types to suit its data quality requirements), then some values may be unintentionally overwritten and depending on your PHP version "Deprecated" warnings may be emitted ([Edge case demo](https://3v4l.org/KpC9Q)).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/V9kNf))

```
var_export(
    array_column($array, 'value', 'attribute')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use a foreach loop. There isn't a "built-in" method of doing this.

```
foreach ($arr as $entry)
{
    $assoc[$entry["attribute"]] = $entry["value"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like what you really should be doing is refactoring your approach, because it feels like you're solving the wrong problem. Why is the array created this way in the first place that you want to re-structure it? Is it that you are getting the data into PHP as a JSON object from some external source, which you have no control over? Or is it that you are building the array in PHP poorly and you now want to restructure it differently because you realized it was giving you trouble to work with that way?

If it's the **former** then you will need to do the following (*build an entirely new array in the new structure you want*):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $element) {
    $new_array[$element['attribute']] = $element['value'];
}
```

If it's the **latter** then you really want to have just built the array in this way in the first place, thus eliminating the need to create a new array in the first place.

Also, if you explain the actual use case there could be an even better solution. It could be that you don't need to do this at all and you're simply wasting your time when the existing structure could be used to accomplish what you need.

Comment: @Supericy 's answer solved it, check my other comment if you want to know why the data looks like this. I'm using Open-Schema for a certain table.